# When transliterating a name for the Ketubah, can the letters י and ה be written together?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, aleph-bet-letters, ketubah

Specifically, the name in this case is Natalya. Is it considered appropriate to spell it as נטליה, which seems like the most correct transliteration?

As a child in a yeshiva, I had teachers who would not write names ending in יה as it contained G-d's name. They would instead write it as just י or replace the ה with an apostrophe. I am wondering if, since the Ketubah is intended to be kept permanently and not destroyed / erased, this consideration would not apply?

Answer (score 2):

If this question is relevant to you, consult your rabbi. (Indeed, if it's relevant to you, then you're getting married — *mazal tov*! — and should have someone officiating your wedding who knows the main rules, knows how to find out the other rules, and will be able to answer this question for you.)

But for background information, here's a source: *Aruch Hashulchan*, *Even Haezer* 129, discusses, in general, the spelling of names in general and, in particular, the spelling of a number of specific names, including a number that end with *yod he*. He does not say to curtail the name before the *he* or to replace the *he* with an apostrophe. (Nor does he indicate that one should put a hyphen or apostrophe between the *yod* and the *he*.)

However, I can think of two reasons this *Aruch Hashulchan* may possibly not apply to your question: First, he's discussing *gitin* (bills of divorce), not *k'subos* (prenuptial agreements), and my impression is that the exactitude we enforce on writing names correctly is stronger for the former. Therefore, perhaps we wouldn't mind modifying a name slightly in a *k'suba*, if there is some benefit to doing so. Second, he does say that the spelling of a name often follows how it is used by the person (how, for example, the person signs that name); it may follow, then, that his not mentioning curtailing or replacing the final *he* in a *get* is because no one signed his name that way in his day (and place) and that it should be done now if the name's owner does so.